# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to read a file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filenotfoundexception, opencsv

I am writing a small app that reads a csv file and displays the contents into a JList.

My current problem is that the `new FileReader(file)` code keeps giving me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error and I am not too sure why.

```
loadFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("~/"));

                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(instance) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    fileLocation.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the exact message of the exception? `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` This should give a pretty good hint on what the problem is. It may be a "Permission denied", or "The system cannot find the file specified", or something else. This is likely to provide interesting information, rather than people making wild guesses on what the problem might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new File("~/")
```

`~` is a Shell shortcut for the home directory. Use an absolute path like

```
new File("/home/myself/")
```

As pointed out by @pickypg, [JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory%28java.io.File%29) sets the user's home directory as default if the passed directory is invalid. So, even though `File()` does not interpret `~` as a Shell does, the `JFileChooser` starts in the user's home directory - but this is true for any non-existing directory, for instance

```
new File("/Windows")   // JFileChooser would start in "\Windows"
new File("/xWindows")   // JFileChooser would start in the user's home directory
```

As the documentation states, the user's home directory is system specific, but on MS Windows it is typically the "My Documents" folder.

But, even when using such an non-existing path as "~/", `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()` returns a proper path, so that `FileReader()` should not throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

---

Based on the comments, it turns out that the issue is not a runtime exception, but a compile time error where the exception is not catched. Add a `try{}catch{}` block around your `FileReader()` constructor:

```
try {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
}catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    // handle exception, e.g. show error message
}
```

Comment: Plus the default directory should be the user's home directory.

Comment: I didn't have any issues using ~/ but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it actually seems to work - in Windows 7 with Java 7, it directs me to the "My Documents" folder. Lets check the documentation ...

Comment: @ChaoticLoki Back to your question ;) I suppose that replacing "~/" with a real existing path did not solve your issue, right? Did you check `System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath())` before `new FileReader()`? Does it point to an existing file?

Comment: I added this in the GUI `fileLocation.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());` and it prints out the absolute path no problem, its an issue with FileReader.

Comment: Can you replace your `actionPerformed()` body with a one-liner like `new FileReader("HardCodeYourPathHere")` and check what happens? (Copy the path from the output you got into the `FileReader` constructor). Additonally, please post the exception including the stack trace you got.

Comment: hmm this is odd.. even hardcoded paths are throwing exceptions..
`java: /Users/Cyberexcel/IdeaProjects/Audio Recorder/src/com/test/audiorecorder/MainForm.java:39: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

Comment: hmm that worked. I'm a little confused, I'm still pretty new to exception handling, why would this throw an error if there was no issues with it in the beginning?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23762/discussion-between-andreas-and-chaoticloki)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is actually at that line, and not where Andreas points out, then construct the `FileReader` directly with the `file` rather than giving it the path:

```
new FileReader(file)
```

Comment: I removed the `.getAbsoluteValue()` but it is still throwing that exception

Comment: Try debugging/printing out and checking the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` before you attempt to instantiate the `FileReader`. The source of the problem is probably there.

Comment: I have done so and it returns the absolutePath absolutely fine.